# Sphinx and wordforms

Tags: sphinx

How could I make Sphinx to recognize "auto" and "car" as similar words?

Let's image I have three database records

```
Andy likes to drive auto.
Mary don't like to drive car.
Bob is going to buy automobile.
```

Here is sample queries and it's results...

```
query: car
result: Mary don't like to drive car.
-------------------------------------
query: auto
result: Andy likes to drive auto.
-------------------------------------
query: automobile
Bob is going to buy automobile.
```

..but I want sphinx to return...

```
query: car
result:
Andy likes to drive auto.
Mary don't like to drive car.
Bob is going to buy automobile.
-------------------------------------
query: auto
result:
Andy likes to drive auto.
Mary don't like to drive car.
Bob is going to buy automobile.
-------------------------------------
query: automobile
result:
Andy likes to drive auto.
Mary don't like to drive car.
Bob is going to buy automobile.
```

I know that Sphinx have stowords, but what should I put into stopwords dictionary to make Sphinx think this way?

Thank you.

Comment: minor observation... I think you meant to put 'Mary don't like to drive car.' as the first result under the 'car' query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you have to do is supply sphinx with a correctly-formatted text file of wordforms in your .conf file.

documentation found here: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-wordforms

```
auto > car
automobile > car
four-wheeled-vehicle-intended-for-public-roads > car
cars > car
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already checked the manual about wordforms. But I can't understand what shoud I do to equate this words. Should I put car > auto, car > automobile, auto > car, auto > automobile, automobile > car, automobile > auto ? Or any less complicated way? Thank you.

Comment: the syntax is [consider this word] > [as this word].  As I tried to demonstrate in my example code you want to use car as the form for each of the other words so that they are all equivalent to sphinx.  Remember that stemming is not performed on wordforms so plurals and such will have to be specified explicitly.

Comment: I've asked the same question at http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5134 and you've answered simultaneusly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example for wordforms morphology with the terms "gearing" and "leverage" as these words are equal terms in finance and should be considered as synonyms (the meaning of both words is "Financial leverage").

Originally your "wordforms.txt" file should contain them listed like this:

```
gear > gear
geared > gear
gearing > gear
gears > gear
……
leverage > leverage
leveraged > leverage
leverages > leverage
leveraging > leverage
```

It means that originally these two words are not connected. In order to fix that you should modify the content of "wordforms.txt" this way:

```
gear > leverage
geared > leverage
gearing > leverage
gears > leverage
……
leveraged > leverage
leverages > leverage
leveraging > leverage
```

This edit connects them (and all their forms). After you edit the "wordforms.txt" file you must save it and re-index your indexes in order to apply the changes.

Now when you search for "gearing" or "leverage" your results will contain both the words along with all their morphological forms.